# Android Butterknife - Add / Remove the OnTextChangedListener inside OnTextChanged

Tags: java, android, android-layout, butterknife

Can you please suggest how to replace the below code using Butterknife?

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
    editText.setText("")
    editText.addTextChangedListener(this)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use like this :

```
@OnTextChanged(value = R.id.edittext, callback = OnTextChanged.Callback.AFTER_TEXT_CHANGED)
```

Comment: That's fine. I need to remove and add listener inside @OnTextChanged method